# Finalizar y volver a comenzar una actividad desde otra clase en java

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código en mi mainActivity:

```
public class ListaMain2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
     Activity actividad = this;
        adapter = new gestionar_adapter(this, nombreTareas_incompleta, idTareas_incompletas, checkedList, actividad);
        listWorks.setAdapter(adapter);
```

y el siguiente en la clase gestionar_adapter que es un adapter personalizado para cada elemento creado en una listView de forma dinámica:

```
ArrayList<String> resultado;
    ArrayList<Long> idTareas;
    ArrayList<Integer> checkedList;
    Activity actividad;

Context contexto;
    
    private static LayoutInflater inflater= null; //sirve para instanciar el archivo de diseño xml creado

    public gestionar_adapter(Context contexto, ArrayList<String> progNombreLista, ArrayList<Long> idTareas, ArrayList<Integer> checkedList, Activity actividad) {
        resultado = progNombreLista;
        this.contexto = contexto;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.idTareas = idTareas;
        this.checkedList = checkedList;
        this.actividad = actividad;
    }

public View getView(final int posicion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tvTitulo;
        FloatingActionButton btn;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Holder holder=new Holder();
        View fila;
        fila = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_personalizada, null);
        tvTitulo=(TextView) fila.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitulo);
        btn=(FloatingActionButton) fila.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonElemenLista);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) fila.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxElementLista);
        checkbox.setTag(String.valueOf(idTareas.get(posicion)));
        if(checkedList.get(posicion) == 1){
            checkbox.setChecked(true);
        }
        tvTitulo.setText(resultado.get(posicion));
        btn.setTag(String.valueOf(idTareas.get(posicion)));
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FeedReaderDbHelper bdDelete = new FeedReaderDbHelper(contexto.getApplicationContext());
                long id = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));
                bdDelete.deleteTarea(id);
                fila.setVisibility(convertView.GONE);


                Intent intent = new Intent(contexto.getApplicationContext(), ListaMain2Activity.class);
                contexto.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                actividad.finish();
                Toast.makeText(contexto.getApplicationContext(), "eyyy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se pulse el botón con el listener se cierre la actividad ListaMain2Activity y se vuelva a crear pero por más que lo intento la aplicación deja de responder cuando llega a esta línea:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(contexto.getApplicationContext(), ListaMain2Activity.class);
                contexto.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                actividad.finish();
```

Comment: Algún error te tuvo que salir en el ide, algún logcat o algo

Comment: Es muy importante agregar el mensaje que se despliega en el LogCAt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se pulse el botón con el
> listener se cierre la actividad ListaMain2Activity y se vuelva a crear

No debes cerrar y volver a abrir la misma `Activity` para recrearla, esto puede causar un error, ya que el contexto se pierde y se provocan errores.

Veo que tienes un `Adapter`, si deseas actualizar la información cuando sus datos cambiaron, simplemente tienes que llamar el método `notifyDataSetChanged()` de tu `Adapter`:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actividad.finish();
```

Necesitas quitar la propiedad .finish()
ya que esta esta cortando el ciclo de vida de tu activity.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).